# iOS push notification issue using push sharp library

Tags: c#, ios, .net, apple-push-notifications

I have been receiving following error while sending push notifications for iOS devices. This has been working fine past few days but has stopped working suddenly I have tried to install the certificate on my local machine but no luck. I am using 2.2.1 version of pushsharp. I have tried to google this error but none of the solutions worked for me. Can anyone please assist?

CODE USED :

```
string cert = appSettings.Where(x => x.Key == "APNS_CUSTOMER_CERT").Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

var appleCert = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Certificate") + "\\" + cert;

push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(true, appleCert, "", true));

AppleNotificationAlert alert = new AppleNotificationAlert();
alert.Body = TickerText;

AppleNotificationPayload p = new AppleNotificationPayload();
p.AddCustom("Msg", BodyText);
p.Badge = 1;

p.Alert = alert;

foreach (var s in additionalData)
{
    p.AddCustom(s.Key, s.Value);
}

push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                            .ForDeviceToken(DeviceToken)//the recipient device id
                            .WithPayload(p)
                            );
```

> **Channel Exception:** PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService ->     System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI
>   failed, see inner exception. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the certificate    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSettings settings,
>   CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.c__AnonStorey0.<>m__1(Object
>   state)
>
> 2016-07-27 19:28:14,681 [136] INFO WebAPI - Failure:
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService -> The maximum number of Send
>   attempts to send the notification was reached!

Comment: We are getting the same issue, is there any solution you found?

Comment: Same issue in our implementation, kindly share if you found a work around.